# How to run Maven command in ant script?

Tags: shell, maven, jenkins, command-line, ant

I am trying to create an ant task to execute a maven command, but I am getting error while running the ant task

```
<target name="Junit">
<exec dir="./MServer/BuildServer/Workspc/CustMgmt" executable="cmd">
<arg value="/C"/>
<arg value="E:\EOM Setup\maven-3.3.9\bin\mvn.bat"/>
<arg value="test" />
</exec>
</target>
```

While am running this, am getting an error: 
'E:\EOM' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file
(I am running on Windows 7)

Comment: Why trying to run Maven via Ant Task? Call it directly without Ant..

Comment: @Aaron not working.. Now showing  'E:\EOM\' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: @khmarbaise My whole project is based on ant, only junit part is of maven. Thats why cant run it without ant

Comment: I would suggest adding mvn.bat to your system PATH so you can easily run it from  any location.

Comment: I would migrate to Maven this makes it easier...

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, we do have a plan to migrate our whole project to Maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around this issue by using Ant's `property` task with the `location` attribute (as opposed to the more common `value` attribute). This will store the value as a properly formatted path. In addition, you can use this to reference mvn.bat instead of typing out the entire path every time.

```
<target name="Junit">
    <property name="mvn.executable" location="E:\EOM Setup\maven-3.3.9\bin\mvn.bat" />

    <exec dir="./MServer/BuildServer/Workspc/CustMgmt" executable="cmd">
        <arg value="/C"/>
        <arg value="${mvn.executable}"/>
        <arg value="test" />
    </exec>
</target>
```